# Linux tcp half open socket

Tags: linux, tcp

I have an application server which is listening for Tcp connection. The clients connecting to this application establish persistent connection with Tcp keepalive. Once in a while I would see that the client finds it has lost connection but the application server isn't aware of it.
I did see high cpu on application server once but I am not sure if it is correlated. Also there was no issue with the network.
Can this be because application server didn't reply to tcp keepalive probes and hence client disconnected?

Comment: "client finds it has lost connection" - what does that mean?

Can you be more specific in problem description? What have you tried to resolve it (wireshark on both sides? debugging?)? Is there any code that could be tested? Do you have a small piece of code that still exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: The client registers socket under epoll and when it finds that readbytes is 0,it signals socket closed. It then closes the socket.